# MikTeX, Anki and Latex in Windows 10. Error executing dvipng. Sorry, but dvipng did not succeed

Tags: miktex, compilation-error, dvisvgm

I have installed Anki and MikTeX in Windows 10 to create anki flashcards with LaTeX. I have installed MikTeX because I read that it's the best way to install dvipng and dvisvgm.

After creating a flashcard example, I got the following error when the program tried to compile it. I have no idea how to solve it. Any suggestions?

```
Error executing dvipng.
Generated file: C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Temp\anki_temp\tmp.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(tmp.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size12.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty"))
No file tmp.aux.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd") [1] (tmp.aux) )
Output written on tmp.dvi (1 page, 268 bytes).
Transcript written on tmp.log.
This is dvipng 1.15 Copyright 2002-2015 Jan-Ake Larsson

Sorry, but dvipng did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\dvipng.log
```

Here is the content of dvipng.log:

```
2019-02-24 12:47:26,503+0100 INFO  dvipng - starting with command line: dvipng -D 200 -T tight tmp.dvi -o tmp.png
2019-02-24 12:47:26,517+0100 INFO  dvipng - running 'initexmf' to refresh the file name database
2019-02-24 12:47:29,551+0100 INFO  dvipng - running 'initexmf' to create font map files
2019-02-24 12:47:31,582+0100 FATAL dvipng - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2019-02-24 12:47:31,583+0100 FATAL dvipng - Info: 
2019-02-24 12:47:31,583+0100 FATAL dvipng - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp
2019-02-24 12:47:31,583+0100 FATAL dvipng - Line: 77
2019-02-24 12:47:31,584+0100 INFO  dvipng - finishing with exit code 1
2019-02-24 12:47:37,285+0100 INFO  dvipng - starting with command line: dvipng -D 200 -T tight tmp.dvi -o tmp.png
2019-02-24 12:47:37,301+0100 INFO  dvipng - running 'initexmf' to refresh the file name database
2019-02-24 12:47:40,429+0100 INFO  dvipng - running 'initexmf' to create font map files
2019-02-24 12:47:42,378+0100 FATAL dvipng - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2019-02-24 12:47:42,378+0100 FATAL dvipng - Info: 
2019-02-24 12:47:42,378+0100 FATAL dvipng - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp
2019-02-24 12:47:42,378+0100 FATAL dvipng - Line: 77
2019-02-24 12:47:42,379+0100 INFO  dvipng - finishing with exit code 1
2019-02-24 12:51:12,899+0100 INFO  dvipng - starting with command line: dvipng -D 200 -T tight tmp.dvi -o tmp.png
2019-02-24 12:51:13,009+0100 FATAL dvipng - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2019-02-24 12:51:13,009+0100 FATAL dvipng - Info: 
2019-02-24 12:51:13,009+0100 FATAL dvipng - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp
2019-02-24 12:51:13,009+0100 FATAL dvipng - Line: 77
2019-02-24 12:51:13,010+0100 INFO  dvipng - finishing with exit code 1
2019-02-24 12:51:13,575+0100 INFO  dvipng - starting with command line: dvipng -D 200 -T tight tmp.dvi -o tmp.png
2019-02-24 12:51:13,597+0100 FATAL dvipng - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2019-02-24 12:51:13,597+0100 FATAL dvipng - Info: 
2019-02-24 12:51:13,597+0100 FATAL dvipng - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp
2019-02-24 12:51:13,597+0100 FATAL dvipng - Line: 77
2019-02-24 12:51:13,598+0100 INFO  dvipng - finishing with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can be an issue with a not yet stable MiKTeX so using MiKTeX-console follow this advice http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation/108490#108490 try to run at least one graphics sample via the built-in TeXworks editor (that uses dvipng thus it confirms updates are completed and functional)

Comment: I don't know how to start the MiKTeX Package Manager, I have installed MiKTeX but that program does not appear in my computer. I have updated MiKTex through theMiKTeX-console

Comment: the (old) package manager is replaced in the MiKTeX-console by the section labelled "packages" and some of the other options such as "Tasks" any time you have run the "update" cycle you SHOULD run both TASKS Update filename database and update font files before continuing. the texworks on the left is the default editor and after an update has finished can be used to test a troublesome tex file such as C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Temp\anki_temp\tmp.tex to test system errors before using a complex editor NOTE with anki you need the error active as it deletes the tmp.tex if you ok the error !!

Comment: see if my guide here helps https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471185/170109

Comment: I am having the same error. Have you got the solution yet? I am using MikTex for wiondows

Comment: I wasn't able to solve it. I endep up giving up. I'm sorry

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem, try opening `MikTeX console` > `Settings` and making sure you've checked `Never install missing packages on the fly`. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run `dvipng -D 200 -T tight tmp.dvi -o tmp.png` in the command prompt within the directory containing `dvi.png` which is stored in the same directory as the generated `tmp.tex`. The error message in Anki will tell you were that is. In your case that is `C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Temp\anki_temp\`. This is the same command Anki executes but fails as you can see in `dvipng.log`. For me, a window popped up saying I was missing libraries and needed to install them. Once they were installed, the window didn't popup the next time I ran the command. This will mean that when Anki tries executing `dvipng` it won't fail because `dvipng` won't try to open a window telling Anki to install libraries.